# Display Post with category id in 5th and 10th place - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to display separate post with category id after 5th and 10th place. I searched for a query and the query shows,

```
<?php $postnum++;
 if ($postnum == 5) { ?>
 <div class="block">
<h2>Blog</h2></div>
<?php } 
if ($postnum == 10) { ?>
<div class="block"><h2>References</h2></div>
<?php }
```

After putting the above code before endwhile, i can see the Blog and References after 5th and 10th place. But while inserting,

```
<?php $postnum++;
     if ($postnum == 5) { ?>
     <div class="block">
    <?php
    query_posts( array(cat=>3, orderby=>post_date, order=>desc) );
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    ?>
    <?php the_title();
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
            </div>

    <?php } 
    if ($postnum == 10) { ?>
    <div class="block"><?php
    query_posts( array(cat=>4, orderby=>post_date, order=>desc) );
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    ?>
    <?php the_title();
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
            </div>

    <?php } </div>
    <?php }
```

The above code doesnot seems to work correctly. Please anyone help me..

Answer (score 0):

Could be a few things.  Check your server logs, but at the very least

```
<?php the_title();
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

is wrong - either you need to add `?>` after `the_title();` or remove `<?php` before `endwhile;`

Similarly, this:

```
<?php } </div>
```

Looks like it's missing a `?>`.

I'd probably add quotes around the `query_posts()` parameters as well, for clarity:

```
query_posts( array('cat'=>3, 'orderby'=>'post_date', 'order'=>'desc') );
```

And I'd read [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) too, just so you're confident `query_posts` is the right approach for you.